# How to create zipfile with size more than 1GB.(size of zip file after compression of required file)

Tags: vb.net, zip

I am trying to create zip file (with vb2005). if the zip file is going to exceed 1GB code wont work... i tried following code.

```
Imports System.IO.Compression
Imports System.IO.Packaging

strDownloadFilePath= txtpath.text

Dim clsNewZip As Package = Nothing

clsNewZip = ZipPackage.Open(strDownloadFilePath, _
     IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate,FileAccess.ReadWrite)

Dim uriFileName As String = strDestinationPath.Replace(" ", "_")

Dim zipUri As String = String.Concat("/", IO.Path.GetFileName(uriFileName))
Dim partUri As New Uri(zipUri, UriKind.Relative)
Dim contentType As String = Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Zip
Dim pkgPart As PackagePart = clsNewZip.CreatePart(partUri,contentType, _
         CompressionOption.Normal)
Dim bites As Byte() = File.ReadAllBytes(strDestinationPath)

pkgPart.GetStream().Write(bites, 0, bites.Length)

clsNewZip.Close()
```

Comment: Don't read all Bytes from the your Source (Why is your source called Destination?). Take a Filestream and copy it blockwise into the target zipstream.

Comment: The reason you want to do as @Ralf says is because you are filling your memory with the entire file. By doing it in blocks, you control the amount of memory used. Be aware though, each block is compressed on it's own, you must unzip the same way. Also, the smaller the block, the less compression.

Comment: @ Ralf...Thanks ...  strDestinationPath its location where file to be compressed is located...

Comment: @Ralf , @ Steve .... do u have any reference link for this...